# Why does redirecting output affect the result of a test in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, return-value, archlinux

I'm trying to write a script to launch xfce and xbmc in their own x sessions.

To do this I'm setting the `DISPLAY` value, running the first one in the background and waiting until I get a successful return from `xset q`. Then I change `DISPLAY` and do the same for the other.

I'm writing this piece by piece to check I've got the syntax right for each part and the part I'm stuck on is the 'waiting until I get a successful return from `xset q`.

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
while [[ ! `xset q` ]]
do
  echo -n "."
done
```

This code seems to work so when XFCE is running it exits immediately and when it is not it sits there printing `.xset: unable to open display ":0.0"`

However I don't want to see the output of `xset` so I'm trying to redirect its output.

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
while [[ ! `xset q > /dev/null 2>&1` ]]
do
  echo -n "."
done
```

Adding this redirection however seems to break the detection, and regardless of whether XFCE is running or not it just sits there printing dots.

I've tested the two commands on their own and in a shell script on their own they both work as I expect, returning 1 when XFCE is not running and 0 when it is.

Can anyone explain why putting that command inside of `` [[ ! `…` ]] `` breaks the `while` test and how I could rewrite this `while` loop correctly?

(Running on Arch)

Comment: The bash redirection `&> file` is equivalent to `> file 2>&1`

Comment: @glenn The bash redirection `&>` is also arguably not posix compliant, and `cmd &> file` should run `cmd` asynchronously and then truncate `file` (eg, it is equivalent to `cmd& : > file;`)  Some shells do treat it that way, and it is best avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not testing the return code of `xset` at all, you  processing it's output. When you redirect the output to `/dev/null`, the expression in backticks doesn't return anything, it's as if you had:

```
while [[ ! '' ]] ...
```

which will always run the `while` body.

What you should be doing is:

```
while ! xset q > /dev/null 2>&1 
do 
  ...
done
```

Comment: Ah. I did try to make sense of all the different bracket syntaxes available but looks like brackets still beat me! ;) many thanks.

Comment: @Styne666 brackets are not syntax. `[` is a command and `[[` is a keyword, but it functions just like a command.